# Как заполнить объект структуры в аргументах функции по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Хочу создать функцию с аргументами по умолчанию:

```
void MaterialDiffuse(D3DCOLORVALUE Difzf = {1,1,1,0}){
     //code
}
```

но аргументы по умолчанию не возможно занести в объект структуры D3DCOLORVALUE.
Как видно конструктора нет:

```
     typedef struct _D3DCOLORVALUE {
         float r;
         float g;
         float b;
         float a;
     } D3DCOLORVALUE;
```

Как можно заполнить струтуру в функции?

---

Кто-то ответил, но удалил ответ. Решение такое(кому-нибудь пригодится):

```
const _D3DCOLORVALUE defaultA = {1.0, 1.0, 10}; 
void MaterialDiffuse(_D3DCOLORVALUE Difzf = defaultA){
     //code 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В C++11 можно так:

```
void MaterialDiffuse(D3DCOLORVALUE Difzf = D3DCOLORVALUE{1,1,1,0}){
     //code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не написать конструктор(-ы) для этой структуры и далее в параметрах функции:

```
void MaterialDiffuse(D3DCOLORVALUE Difzf = D3DCOLORVALUE (1,1,1,0)){
    .......
 }
```